# Notify the Adapter to update Image of every item

Tags: android, adapter, updating

Ive got an Adapter with items you can click on. Every item has an image. if you didnt click on it, it shows a flag. if you click on it a new activity opens with some details. if you press back the image shall be changed to a hook. how do i update this the best way? i tried

```
//Quick written 
override onresume(){
   super.onresume(); 
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

but the viewholder didnt update the items!

Comment: How do you set the hook image in the item?

Comment: in onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder ivHolder, int position){
ivHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hook_white_24dp);
}

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?